# Windows Azure SQL Scripting

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, sql-scripts

I am in the process of creating a simple script for a Windows Azure Hosted Database, that will change the value of one column in one table.  The script needs to be scheduled to run every 24 hours. Pretty basic stuff I would have thought.

However my complications start with the fact that I cannot create a stored Procedure in SQL. All my research has told me to create a Mobile Service with Azure which I have done but being a novice I am unsure of the approach in terms of configuration or syntax. I am now unsure whether this is even the right approach

I can also see a new Login created for my SQL database when I connect using SSMS. I presume I have to give this login permission somehow.

If anyone is able to point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: Show your approaches

Comment: Does a scheduled job in Windows or SQLServer solve the problem?  Why can't you create stored procs?  If you can't, how bout just using a paramterized query instead?

Comment: Please take a look at scheduler. Mobile Services is not the right tech for this. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following [blog](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/) and example [code](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-Automation-Your-SQL-30f8736b). Because SQL Agent is not an option in Azure SQL Database, [Azure Automation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/automation/) is a great way to schedule jobs against a SQL Database.

Comment: Hi,Thank you all very much for the replies.